# Random walk and inequality involving the Green function on N step

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I would like to check if my arguments are the correct ones in proving

$$
G_N(x,y):=\sum_{k=0}^N P_x[X_k=y]\leq G_N(y,y)
$$

where **$X$ is a random walk** on $\mathcal{Z}$ with $E_0[|X_1|]<\infty$ and $E_0[X_1]=0$. This is part of the discussion that precedes Theorem 17.41 in Probability Theory, 3rd version, by A. Klenke.

My attempt, where $\tau_y^1=\inf\{n>0: X_n=x\}$, $N\in \mathcal{N}$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N P_x[X_k=y]\stackrel{1}{=}\sum_{k=0}^N \sum_{l=0}^NP_x[X_k=y,\tau_y^1=l]
\\\stackrel{2}{=}\sum_{l=0}^N\sum_{k=l}^{N}P_x[X_k=y,\tau_y^1=l]\\
\stackrel{3}{=}\sum_{l=0}^N\sum_{k=l}^{N}P_y[X_{k-l}=y]P_x[\tau_y^1=l]
\\\stackrel{4}{=}\sum_{l=0}^N\sum_{k=0}^{N-l}P_y[X_k=y]P_x[\tau_y^1=l]
\\\stackrel{5}{=}\sum_{l=0}^NP_x[\tau_y^1=l]G_{N-l}(y,y)
\\ \leq \sum_{l=0}^NP_x[\tau_y^1=l]G_{N}(y,y)
\\ \leq G_N(y,y).
$$

I used:

- $1^{st}$ equality: Law of Total Probability
- $2^{nd}$ equality: $P_x[X_k=y,\tau_y^1=l]=0$ for $k<l$
- $3^{rd}$ equality: Markov property
- $1^{st}$ inequality: $G_{N-l}(y,y)\leq G_N(y,y)$ because the number of times the process visits $y$ in a "shorter period" is less than in a "greater period" starting from $y$
- $2^{nd}$ inequality: $\sum_{l=0}^NP_x[\tau_y^1=l] \leq 1$

Let me know if more context is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost correct, but there is a small error.
On the right-hand side of the third equality, the correct summand is $P_{y}[X_{k-l} = y]P_{x}[\tau_{y}^{1} = l]$.
This is because, due to the strong Markov property, the probability $P_{x}[X_{k} = y, \tau_{y}^{1} = l]$ is equal to the product of the probabilities "$X$ hits $y$ for the first time at $l$" and "$X$, starting from $y$, hits $y$ at $k-l$".
The rest of the computation can be done in much the same way as you originally did.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I find a little bit strange to change it since it is the only one step given explicitly by the author in the book. Is it a possible mistake to signal to him?

Comment: Since I do not have access to that book, I do not know the exact description, but the third equality does not hold.
Actually, by deleting the third equality, the computation is correct (i.e., the second line and the fourth are equal, but the second and the third are not).

To show the third equality is wrong, let us consider the case where X is a 1-dim simple symmetric random walk.
Then $P_{y-1}[X_{1} = y, \tau^{1}_{y} = 1] = 1/2$, but $P_{y}[X_{1} = y] P_{y-1}[\tau_{y}^{1} = 1] = 0$.

Comment: I edited the OP and also changed where I applied the Markov property: from 4th to 3rd equality. Is it ok now? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I think it's correct.